# Spurious epoll (edge triggered) notifications

Tags: multithreading, epoll

My understanding of epoll and edge triggered behaviour was that you are notified when a state change occurs for a given file descriptor.  Ie, when data becomes available on the fd, you get notified but you only get notified again after you drain all the data (you get `EAGAIN`) and data becomes present again.

Based on this understanding, I'd implemented a server which does the following:

1. Listens for client connections
2. For each connections, add fd into epoll
3. When data available on fd, spawn a separate thread to read until `EAGAIN`
4. Repeat until data reads are done

Semi pseudo-code:

```
n = epoll_wait(efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    check for errors;
    if (server_sock == events[i].data.fd) {
        conn = accept( ... );
        make_nonblocking(conn);
        event.data.fd = conn;
        event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP;
        epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, conn, &event);
    } else {
        spawn_reader(events[i].data.fd);
    }
```

With the above code, my expectation was that until the reader thread hits `EAGAIN`, epoll will not spawn another thread for this fd.  This doesn't seem to be the case and I get many threads being spawned.

Am I using epoll incorrectly?  I shouldn't need to remove the fd via `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` each time I spawn the reader thread, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its working as it should. epoll allows asynchronous IO programming in a single thread of control (event driven). Using a thread to process reads on an fd does not remove it from the list of monitored fds.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think I'm still not fully clear about epoll behavior, but based on experimentation, I'm thinking my interpretation of what is considered a 'state change' is incorrect?  I would have expected that if an fd received 1kB of data, until I read that data epoll_wait won't unblock again, but I observe that the second 1kB data sent will unblock.  I'm guessing that until some buffer used by the kernel for this connection is 'full', I'll keep getting notifications?

Comment: Right. The wait and the read are completely independent. This is not a problem when wait/read are in the same thread of control. When they are in different threads you will need some strategy to inform the reader thread that there is more data. Or as you mentioned above remove and add fds in the wait thread.